# Updating list in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

How one can update  a list in dynamodb. consider the following example

```
Section:"A",
Group:[{Name:"Albert",
  Age:24},
  {Name:"Antony",
    Age:25}],
GroupName:"Ply"
```

Now I need to change Alberts age from **24** to **26**, considering **Section** as my primary partition key

```
 var params = {
 TableName: "Add_list",
 Key:{
 Section:"A"
  },
 "UpdateExpression" : "#Key = :value",
  "ConditionExpression":"#Key1 = :value1",
 "ExpressionAttributeNames" : {
 "#Key" : "Group",
 "#Key1":"Group[0].Name"
 },
 "ExpressionAttributeValues" : {
 ":value" : [{Name:"Albert",Age:26}],
 ":value1" : "Albert"
  }
  };
```